# How do I create a realistic world and country?

Tags: cities

I know this is a very broad question, so I'll try to narrow this down.

I'm writing a novel about faeries who live in another realm, and the faeries live on an island. The capital city is there too, called Seren. There is a wealthy and non-wealthy district in the city, and the castle is there too since the government is a monarchy. I was wondering: since there is a literal castle in the capital city, should there be a poorer community in there at all? Or should I make the poorer community a whole other city? Or am I just overthinking this?

(I'm relatively new to this S.E., I haven't written too many questions here so if this question is at all bad or irrelevant I'll modify it as needed, just let me know.)

Comment: Well, London was the capital of England since always. It has a castle, a few rich districts and a few poor districts -- just like any city anywhere. (You cannot have a city where everybody is rich, because rich people need a lot of poor people to work for them.)

Comment: You have a few thoughts in the question body that can be great questions if you elaborate. Have you thought about breaking those into several different questions? The current question title is way too broad, I'd change that.

Comment: What's tech/societal level you're imagining?

Comment: The idea of a place where only rich people live is something that has only existed since the internal combustion engine.

Answer (score 8):

**It can be very realistic if you model it on something real.**

If you like having a king in the city, and rich areas and poor areas you can find historical precedent.  London, maybe?

[image: london 1300]
([Image Source](http://www.emersonkent.com/map_archive/london_1300.htm))

> William’s son, William II, began Westminster Hall in 1097, which had
> the effect of further solidifying London as the capital of England.
> Prior to this, the heart of political power was wherever the king held
> court, but the building of the hall was the beginning of the Palace of
> Westminster and the centralization of that power in one location.
> While kings still used the Tower of London, the Palace of Westminster
> became their home and the City of London became the economic center,
> while Westminster became the seat of government. ([Source](https://londontopia.net/site-news/featured/life-medieval-london/#:%7E:text=While%20kings%20still%20used%20the,became%20the%20seat%20of%20government))

It is not plagiarism to copy old London, or anywhere else that suits your fancy as long as it is real.  If you don't actually call it "London" no-one will be the wiser!  And you can actually find maps of the city in the year that you want which will help you plot your characters' movements.  If you are good enough at it, maybe one of your readers who is familiar with the old city will realize what you are up to, and smile.

Comment: London and other cities change greatly over time, so find the version that suites you, or better yet, a few cities combined. I've read a Rome+Egyptian city combination that was pretty cool somewhere

Answer (score 1):

What is the history?

This hold the answer to your question.

Yes in history there are many example of poor neighborhoods following richer ones but you can also undo that by having a nobility that actively pushes out people below a certain level of their cities.

### City A, the typical approach

City A started as a simple town that followed the lords little castle. The castle got bigger and the lord got bigger and as such the town got bigger and bigger.
As expected the rich need the poor to do stuff for them and as the rich has the money the poor also need the rich to get some of the money. The original poor sectors of the city is smaller and simpler.
But people from the country side come here and as many of them had little money or connection they could afford little to no housing.
Now it does not take a genius to figure that money can be made selling cheap rooms and cheap ale and cheap meals to those people.
So. They settle in the the poorest places where the price for a bed includes the bugs and smells. But it's a roof and a warm meal.
As those people work and start getting some money, I mean if they just starve to death then they are dead, they rarely earn enough to afford much.
So. They graduate from the worst thing to the second worst thing.
But the continual influx of poor people keep the cheapest hotels and brothels full.
Some climb out of poverty and join the higher classes who then keeps enough distance between them and the poorest. Other remain like we said.
So. As the size of the town grows and economics change the poor and rich neighborhoods also changed.

### Get off my lawn

The rich here are not fans of poor people. Getting into the city requires a recommendation or showing a useful skill. Otherwise you are not admitted or if admitted quickly thrown out.

Now this can lead to people setting up outside the city gates but if you are determined enough you can even destroy those places and again kick the people.
You can pass a law or just really be big on throwing people out of there.

Of course this is mostly your world so if you imagine a particular monarch who is really against the poor people even within a kilometer of his city then sure.

Yes most of the time if there are chances for a better life and money to be made they can be set up a few kilometers from the city. Corrupt guards or official can
make money on the side.

**Why would people risk it? For a better life. Do I even need to mention contemporary examples?**

### Marxism before it was cool. `please read as you do a cheesy ad`

Hey comrade. Join our glorious utopia where there are no classes. Wait we have a monarchy? No worries. Our super chill king passed a law to provide all citizen-subject of our kingdom with some basic rights such as food, water, housing...etc

All for the simple act of signing up at the ministry of work affairs.
Once you come to our city and sign up you are given the full rights of a subject-citizen of our glorious capital. You will be given coin, food, and shelter.

The offices are everywhere but you can pick where you want to sing, all the same.

**But all the king asks in return is simple labor as the office of working directs you to do. You don't want to be ungrateful to his majesty do you?**

So. Once you come you are then shipped where the kingdom and your fellow citizen-subjects need your work and steady hand. Mining, fishing, farming, soldiering...etc are some of the exciting stuff you will do. And do it long enough and well enough then you get a shinny medal.

Don't worry. It's a lot of fun. And you don't have to worry about being left out as the commissars roam the kingdom to sing you up in from the comfort of your own house.

What are you waiting for?

*Failure to comply is punished by the law, consult your nearest commissariat office to figure out when will you be shipped to NOT Gulag to do work there for free.*

---

Honestly there are no rules because even historical approaches only tells you of history not that all history even imagined ones should follow. And as long as things are not too insane then I don't see an issue with: **Doing whatever you feel like for the story. Because most approaches are context dependent.**